# Is there a good reason why classes have lock objects tied to them?

Tags: c#, memory, locking

If I understand correctly any instance of a `class` has a **lock object** by default.

## Proof

When we enter the "lock" then the memory above our actual data is being set.

```cs
var d = new Data();

d.x0 = 1;
d.x1 = 2;
d.x2 = 3;
d.x3 = 4;

lock (d) 
{   // <---- when we're here.
    
}
```

[image]

and get out of the scope.

```cs
var d = new Data();

d.x0 = 1;
d.x1 = 2;
d.x2 = 3;
d.x3 = 4;

lock (d) 
{   
    
}    // <---- when we're here.
```

then the `1` in the memory disappears.

[image]

### Details

Now if you want to see how it behaves without `lock` keyword -> Let us create 2 classes and execute our code in `Release` mode (so we can get the right/optimized version + memory is more readable).

```cs
var d1 = new Data();

d1.x0 = 1;
d1.x1 = 1;
d1.x2 = 1;
d1.x3 = 1;

var d2 = new Data();

d2.x0 = 2;
d2.x1 = 2;
d2.x2 = 2;
d2.x3 = 2;
```

So no `lock` is used. Now let's see how the memory is aligned. As you can see in the image: it does *NOT* allocate our second instance right after first one, there is a gap of `00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`, which proves that C# allocates extra memory for each instance. And testing the very first snippet you'll see that it is indeed for locking purposes.

[image]

## Question

Is there a good reason why we have that? I mean most of the time we're NOT locking our objects. Isn't this wasteful?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit your affirmation? As far as I know, classes do not have locking mechanisms by default, that is reason the coder the one that has to code them when concurrency could happen and cause problems in those classes.

Comment: @Cleptus my question is why do we "allocate" extra space for locking when most of the time we don't use our objects for locking.

Comment: Do you still see the lock object if you remove the `lock` statement? What you are seeing is just how the `lock` statement is implemented. You need to ask the C# language team to know exactly why they implemented it in this particular way...

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, I do see that. That's why I want to know if there is any reason for it.

Comment: The part relative to the "proof" section of the question is imho a bit lacking, please edit the question and elaborate how you reached the hypothesis of that `00 00 00 00 01 00 00` being a copy of the instance when the code has no `lock` statement (Sweeper's comment).

Comment: @Cleptus updated my question. Tell me if you need more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation is a bit more complicated than that. All objects have a header and a method table pointer, each is 4 or 8 bytes depending on the platform. Notably the header is used for more things than locking.

> 1. Locking
> 2. GC information. E.g.
>
>    - Bits to mark objects
>    - Generation of the object
>    - Whether the object is pinned
> 3. Hashcode (for GetHashCode support)
> 4. Size of the object

Sources: [Managed object internals, Part 1. The layout](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/managed-object-internals-part-1-layout/),  [CLR Managed Object overhead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/abhinaba/wp7-clr-managed-object-overhead)

The reasoning behind decisions of internal teams is difficult to find out without first hand knowledge. So this is based on conjecture.

They probably want the header to be the same size as an pointer to keep alignment. Since all of the bits in the header are not used for other purposes they might as well use some of them for locking. Note that the bits in the header may not be sufficient for using it as a lock. If that is the case some of the bits are repurposed as a pointer into a separate table.

> As you may know, every managed object has an auxiliary field for every object called the object header. The header itself can be used for different purposes and can keep different information based on the current object’s state.

> The CLR can store object’s hash code, domain specific information, lock-related data and some other stuff at the same time. Apparently, 4 bytes of the object header is simply not enough for all of that. So, the CLR will create an auxiliary data structure called sync block table and will keep just an index in the header itself. But the CLR will try to avoid that and will try to put as much data in the header itself as possible.

Source: [Managed object internals, Part 2. Object header layout and the cost of locking](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/managed-object-internals-part-2-object-header-layout-and-the-cost-of-locking/)

So it would be incorrect to claim that "classes have lock objects tied to them". Rather, *objects* have *headers*, and part of the header contains information related to locking.

Comment: If I understand correctly the header is used for multiple things. Is there a list of them? Locking as I understand is one of them.

Comment: @Hrant The second link has a table with the info of what those bits are used for.

Comment: Found it in your link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/abhinaba/wp7-clr-managed-object-overhead. Maybe you can add them in your answer.